# Pasar proyecto angular a produccion

Tags: angular, webpack

Estoy tratando de exportar el proyecto a producción, pero sólo me funciona cuando lo pongo en la raíz del servidor.

Si, por ejemplo, lo pongo en `localhost/dist` ya no funciona.

He probado a modificar la ruta con el comando `ng build --base-href=/dist --prod`, pero, a pesar de que la modifica sigue sin funcionar, por lo tanto, entiendo que algo estoy haciendo mal.

La idea es poder exportar el proyecto para poder usarlo en una ruta que no sea la base del servidor, dado que necesito ponerlo en varias carpetas diferentes, una por cliente.

He conseguido que se vea con el `<base href="http://localhost/Proyecto/dist/">`

Pero no me linkea bien las imagenes, entiendo que es porque en código el link esta mal, pero si ejecuto el live server de webpack se ve bien (npm start)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Proyecto</title>
    <base href="http://localhost/Proyecto/dist/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.734eae50a5c982a6cd75.css">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.7a0e6866a34e280f48e7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.95f63946aa03ea45d109.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.c686d7d3bc65f8946dda.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: En tu servidor tienes que apuntar a la carpeta deseada ej: `dist/web-app`, después en tu angular.json deberías poner en `... "options": { "outputPath": "dist/web-app", ...` pruébalo y me comentas

Comment: Con el `base` debe de funcionar. Ahora mismo no recuerdo mucho si en el ng build está la opción de --base-href. Puedes comprobar que en el html generado existe el tag `<base href="...">`?

Comment: @aldanux He cambiado la ruta, simplemente es donde sirve el contenido del build, no es exactamente a lo que yo me refería, gracias por tu comentario

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Te he añadido el código final al hacer el build, como ves si se sirve, pero me resulta algo extraño que sea con http. ¿Está bien?

Comment: Prueba con `<base href="dist">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He tenido que poner la ruta de la web, con el HTTPS, funciona perfecto, no se si es lo correcto, pero es la única solución que me ha funcionado correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Yo también tuve el mismo problema, la solución para mi fue dejar vacía `base`.
Es decir:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Proyecto</title>
    <base href="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.734eae50a5c982a6cd75.css">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.7a0e6866a34e280f48e7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.95f63946aa03ea45d109.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.c686d7d3bc65f8946dda.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Confirmo que también me ha funcionado poner: <base href=""> En vez de especificar la ruta <base href="http://localhost/Proyecto/dist/">